# Tkinter scrollbar initializes scrolled to bottom

Tags: python, tkinter

In Tkinter I've created a `Frame` that displays a bunch of data from a pandas `DataFrame`. To fit within the space I have in my real application, I need a `Scrollbar`. In the MRE below, I create some headers that I don't want to move and then the main data that should move along with the scrollbar. It *almost* works. The only problem is that the scrollbar initializes at the bottom of the dataset for some reason. I've worked with Tkinter for a long time and never had this happen.

I tried using `can.yview_moveto(0)` and placed that line in a few different spots in the loop sequence, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Everything about this MRE has the behavior I want except for the initial position of the scrollbar.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class TestClass(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 5), 
                            columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
        
        mf = Frame(self.parent)
        mf.pack()
        scroll = Scrollbar(mf, orient='vertical')
        scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        can=Canvas(mf, yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
        can.pack(side='bottom', fill='both', expand=True)
        scroll.config(command=can.yview)
        qfrm = Frame(can)
        lfrm = Frame(mf) 
        lfrm.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        can.create_window((0,0), window=qfrm, anchor='w')
        qfrm.bind('<Configure>', 
                lambda event, canvas=can: self.onFrameConfigure(canvas))
        (Label(lfrm, text='Title of the Frame')
                .grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=5, pady=5))
        c=0
        w=6
        for d in df.columns:
            r=0
            #Inserts headers
            Label(lfrm, text=d, width=w).grid(column=c, row=1)
            for i in df.index:
                #Inserts data
                (Label(qfrm, text=round(df.loc[i, d], 2), width=w)
                        .grid(row=r, column=c, sticky=EW))
                r+=1
        
            c+=1
        can.yview_moveto(0)
        

    def onFrameConfigure(self, canvas):
        #Fixes scrollbar on tkinter canvas
        canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=Tk()
    ui = TestClass(root)
    ui.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please remove the Pandas tag

Comment: Why the votedown on the question?